# Why doesn't my AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event always fire?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a Windows Service program running in Release mode that runs 24/7 which makes some in-process COM calls to a C++ library and occasionally it crashes but the log4net log call in the **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException** event doesn’t fire.

Instead the process just terminates and a EventLog log message is written … but what’s strange again is that my code doesn’t have any EventLog.WriteEntry calls.

Can some help me figure out why the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is not firing in all cases?

Thanks in advance

Event log message:

> EventType clr20r3, P1 ProgramName.exe, P2 0.0.0.0, P3 4d5bd49f, P4 mscorlib, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4a7cd8f7, P7 41b3, P8 a3, P9 system.argumentoutofrange, P10 NIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry in the event log is written by Windows, and is telling you that something is throwing an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx). Without seeing the code contained in your event handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, it's difficult to say *why*, but it's very likely one of the following is occuring:

- Your exception handler is throwing the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
- You have multiple AppDomain's in your process and it's one of the other ones throwing the argument out of range exception.

The former is more likely. Review the code in your exception handler *very carefully* and look for anywhere that a bad argument could be passed. You could try wrapping the entire exception handler in a `try``catch` that logs any exception that occurs **within** your exception handler to the event log and see if that get you any further information, such as a stack trace.

Also, make sure that you're deploying the debug symbols (`.pdb` files) with your application so that any stack traces that get logged give you line numbers to refer back to.

Comment: Hi, there's only 1 appDomain and the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event just has 1 log4net call.

Comment: @arkina, then are you *100%* sure that your event handler is being hit and that your log4net call isn't being passed any `null`s? =)